# Does all the text in cell use the same font?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working with some Excel files that typically have lots of text inside cells. I'd like to run a check to ensure that all the text is the same font (specifically, Calibri).

At the moment, I have this way of doing it. But it runs extremely slow.

```
Function fnCalibriCheck() As String

Dim CurrentCell As Range                                ' The current cell that is being checked
Dim SelectedRng As Range                                ' The selection range
Dim F As Long
Set SelectedRng = ActiveSheet.Range(Selection.Address)  ' Defines the selection range

For Each CurrentCell In SelectedRng                     ' Goes through every cell in the selection and performs the check

    For F = 1 To Len(CurrentCell)
        If CurrentCell.Characters(F, 1).font.Name <> "Calibri" Then
            fnCalibriCheck = "not calibri"
        End If
    Next

Next
End Function
```

The problem seems to be specific to the Font.Name property. For example, if I run the same code, but instead of Font.Name I search for a specific character, then it runs perfectly fine. As it is though, my current macro can take several seconds to run, and occasionally crashes.

I'm wondering if anyone can suggest a better alternative.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can speed it up considerably by exploiting the following behavior of a `Range` `Font.Name` property:

- if *all* characters of *all* cells in the `range` have the same font then it returns that font name
- if *any* characters of *any* cell in the `range` has a different font than *any* other character of *any* other cell then it returns `Null`

so you can simply code:

```
Function fnCalibriCheck() As String
    If IsNull(Selection.Font.Name = "Calibri") Then fnCalibriCheck = "not Calibri"
End Function
```

which you can make a little more general by accepting the range to scan and the font to check as parameters

```
Function fnFontCheck(rng As Range, fontName As String) As String
    If IsNull(rng.Font.Name = fontName) Then fnFontCheck = "not " & fontName
End Function
```

and which could be called like follows:

```
MsgBox fnFontCheck(Selection, "Calibri")
```

Comment: Brilliant. I was thinking about trying to do something similar with error handling code, but this is much more concise. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 3):

You might get a slight speed improvement by passing the range rather than using `Select` and immediately returning on the first failure:

```
Function fnCalibriCheck(SelectedRng As Range) As String

    Dim CurrentCell As Range
    Dim F As Long

    fnCalibriCheck = "calibri"
    For Each CurrentCell In SelectedRng
        If CurrentCell.Value <> "" Then
            For F = 1 To Len(CurrentCell)
                If CurrentCell.Characters(F, 1).Font.Name <> "Calibri" Then
                    fnCalibriCheck = "not calibri"
                    Exit Function
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: I ended up going with user3598756's solution, but thanks!

Comment: @garroad_ran  Consider marking the user3598756 post as ***Answer***